Exporting attribute table of atlas features as CSV in QGIS Atlas
I have an atlas in QGIS 3.28, I would like to export the attribute table of the features visible in the atlas as a CSV (or similar).
I know I can add the attribute table to the atlas itself but the tables are too big to format nicely like this and I want a record of every field - and there are over one hundred features.
Is there a way to save this information to a file instead? Ideally, I would like to have a separate CSV file for each atlas page with only the features visible on that page in the file (for a given layer).
Is there a straightforward way to do this? Or can anyone point me to a Python script that might do so?

If the number of atlas pages is not too big, you could create a virtual layer in your QGIS main window, that lists the features lying within one feature of your atlas coverage layer.
Something like:
SELECT * FROM features AS a , atlas_coverage_layer AS b
WHERE b.fieldname = 'name of your current atlas page' AND ST_Within( a.geometry , b.geometry )

Then you can export the table to a csv file.
I am sure, that someone who knows more about SQL than me could write you the code for a virtual layer that iterates automatically over your atlas features.

This worked perfectly for my limited atlas and is an excellent answer! Although, I think b.pagename  might be better described as b.field_name (I spent a while trying to work out where the variable pagename was defined...)

You can create an atlas layout and build a model with QGIS Model Builder. Set up your model so it prints your atlas as well as a CSV output.
This model can be exported as pure PyQGIS script, if that is your preferred way to save the workflow.
